# Q: Create and Send envelope with template with REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to add the new witness functionality to my API call. Heres the json that I am sending now:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[my id]/envelopes

{
"emailSubject":"test",
"status":"sent",
"templateId":"[Valid template id]",
"templateRoles":[
{
  "roleName":"sign1",
  "email":"valid@email.com",
  "name":"John",
  "recipientId":"1",
  "routingOrder":"1",
  "tabs":{}
},
{
  "roleName":"Witness for sign1",
  "witnessFor":"sign1",
  "witnessForGuid":"1",
  "recipientId":"2",
  "routingOrder":"2",
  "recipientType":"witness"
}
]
}
```

I have configured the template in DocuSign and verified the functionality by sending an envelope via the DocuSign website. However, the envelopes created from my API call does not trigger the witness functionality. I am not sure what I am missing, and I really appreciate any help/feedbacks.

Cheers

Comment: Does your template have two recipients or just one?
I seem to remember a "sign with witness" being a type of recipient, which suggests you only have a single recipient. Your API call includes two of them, so I think you need to merge them into one and ensure you have the exact/correct roleName!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a successful Envelopes::create call that includes the `witness` recipient type:

```
"recipients": {
  "witnesses": [
    {
      "name": "Witness Name",
      "email": "witness@example.com",
      "recipientId": "2",
      "witnessFor": "1"
    }
  ],
  "signers": [
    {
      "email": "someone@example.com",
      "name": "Signer name",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "clientUserId": "1000",
      "tabs": {
        "signHereTabs": [
          {
            "anchorString": "/sig1/",
            "anchorXOffset": "20",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

### Suggested changes in your templateRoles attributes:

(Not tested)

I'm assuming that you have a witness role set in the template.
If you don't, then I think you'll need to add the additional `witness` recipient to the envelope via composite templates.

You can also try your idea of including `"recipientType":"witness"`

At the API level, the witness is a distinct recipient for the envelope. It could also the case that the DocuSign web tool creates a hidden recipient (and recipient role) for the witness. To determine if this is the case, use [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see what the DocuSign web tool is actually doing.

```
"templateRoles":[
{
  "roleName":"sign1",
  "email":"valid@email.com",
  "name":"John",
  "recipientId":"1",
  "routingOrder":"1",
  "tabs":{}
},
{
  "roleName":"Witness for sign1",
  "witnessFor":"1",
  OMIT THIS: "witnessForGuid":"1",
  "recipientId":"2",
  OMIT THIS: "routingOrder":"2",
  OMIT THIS: "recipientType":"witness"
}
]
```

### Note

Older developer sandbox accounts don't include the witness feature. If you receive the error message of not having the witness feature, contact go-live  --at-- docusign.com to have the feature added to your developer account.

Comment: Hi Larry, thank you for this great writeup, I definitely learnt a lot about DocuSign's platform. Unfortunately, I am unable to get any of your suggestions working. However, I managed to get it working with the old Template action. It turns out to be a bug in DocuSign where we cannot set the status to sent immediately, we have to split the call into 2 steps. I will write it up in my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a bug in DocuSign, I had to split the creation step into 2.

1st POST /envelopes:

```
{
  "emailSubject":"Template Action Test",
  "status":"created",
  "templateId":"866fcb03-1342-4678-9dc3-107772c59e89",
  "templateRoles":[
    {"roleName":"sign1","email":"email@test.com","name":"JK","tabs":{}}
]
}
```

2nd PUT /envelopes/envelope-id:

```
{
"status":"sent"
}
```